# Changing a location string to const breaks my logger class

Tags: c#, multithreading, mono, constants, readonly

I've been struggling with an issue that recently popped up with a simple logtofile class I wrote.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading;

namespace Assets.Code
{
    class TimingLogger
    {
        public static readonly TimingLogger Logger = new TimingLogger();
        private static readonly string path = "C:\\Logs\\TimingLog.txt";
        private readonly Mutex mutex = new Mutex(false, path);
        private StreamWriter writer;
        private readonly Queue<string> queue = new Queue<string>();
        private bool isRunning;
        private readonly object obj = new object();

        private TimingLogger()
        {

        }

        public void CheckPath()
        {
            if (!File.Exists(path))
            {
                File.Create(path);
            }
        }

        public void Run()
        {
            isRunning = true;
            while (isRunning)
            {
                lock (obj)
                {
                    while (queue.Count <= 0)
                    {
                        Monitor.Wait(obj);
                    }
                    Log(queue.Dequeue());
                }
            }
        }

        public void Log(string line)
        {
            try
            {
                mutex.WaitOne();
                writer = File.AppendText(path);
                writer.WriteLine(line);
                writer.Close();
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                //throw;
            }
            finally
            {
                mutex.ReleaseMutex();
            }
        }

        public void Enqueue(string line)
        {
            lock (obj)
            {
                queue.Enqueue(line);
                Monitor.Pulse(obj);
            }
        }

        public void Stop()
        {
            isRunning = false;
        }
    }
}
```

This class was working just fine until recently, when I noticed that my log file wasn't showing the data I expected. Strangely enough, I hadn't changed any functionality of the class. Comparing an old, working version with my new one, the only difference was that some of my fields were made `private` and `readonly`. Besides that, the `string path` was changed to `const`. And to my complete bewilderment, changing this back to `readonly` fixed the issue I was having.

So my question is: How on earth is this possible? As far as I'm aware, there shouldn't functionally be any difference between readonly and const in this situation.

When debugging, the change in behavior is substantial, especially in the `Run()` method. What **should** happen here is that once `Log(queue.Dequeue());` has been called, the thread will leave the `lock` statement and iterate through the `while (isRunning)` loop again. This seems pretty obvious, right? However, when I change the `string path` to `const` and debug again, the `Log(queue.Dequeue());` is passed once and a single statement can be found in the log file, after which it simply doesn't do anything else ever again. It doesn't come past `while (isRunning)` again and it doesn't seem to leave the `lock (obj)` block. The logger thread seems to simply shutdown or pause after successfully calling `Log(queue.Dequeue());` once.

Actually throwing the exception in the `Log` method makes no difference, no exceptions are thrown because the logging itself works fine.

I should mention that I'm using this code with Unity3D 5, which uses Mono. But still, this drastic change in behavior by such a small edit seems impossible to me. Can anyone explain why this is happening?

Thanks!

Comment: I thought it was a bit too much code to post inside the message body but alright, I've added it.

Comment: It's much better than a link that might vanish and make your question incomprehensible at a later point. Writing a logger is a tricky business that has already been solved. Wouldn't it be better to use an existing solution such as [nLog](http://nlog-project.org/)?

Comment: Funny that you should mention that, I did try nLog but I encountered some problems getting it to work with Unity3D 5. Just to reiterate, my logger works fine now that I've pinpointed and fixed the problem. I just don't understand the problem.

Comment: Probably not the issue but put `mutex.WaitOne();` before the `try` - if that statement throws an exception, a new exception is thrown in the finalizer (perhaps it should be wrapped in another try/catch).

Comment: Interesting, wrapping 'mutex.ReleaseMutex();' in a try/catch **does** show an exception there, but only when debugging. 'Mutex is now owned' is the exception. Sadly I don't have the time to research this further today. More to come! :)

Answer (score 1):

Here is the difference:

Consts are created in the metadata of the files, so when you run you class the value is already there.

ReadOnly are initialized in compile time, in your case, heres the trick, even though you declared path first then the mutex, the compiler initialized the mutex object first, here is why:

Your first static object to be initialized is the Logger:

```
public static readonly TimingLogger Logger = new TimingLogger();
```

Because you called the constructor, the non static members are initialized, making mutex the next member to be initialized. At this point you didnt initialized path yet, so 
you are creating your mutex object with parameters false and null.

If you want to have the same error that you have with const using readonly, you can force the order of your static parameters initialization using a static constructor like :

```
static TimingLogger()
{
    path = "C:\\Logs\\TimingLog.txt";
    Logger = new TimingLogger();
}
```

Or simply putting path before Logger.

If you don't want to have the error using const, just change the mutex initialization using null parameter:

```
private readonly Mutex mutex = new Mutex(false, null);
```